# Python-StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python

has anyone come across the stale error in Python??
I'm still new to Python(3 weeks to date) and I developed from nothing(in programming) to the following. But I am really stuck with the stale element error, it seems the reference is lost when the page is refresh and its only attached to the DOM(whatever that means) and I spent a few days trying to understand this and rectify it by including various implicit and explicit wait but it does not get rid of the problems. Sometimes it failed after two iteration sometimes after 20. Could someone please help. With thanks,Iverson

Comment: I am afraid browser content is changed (e.g. go forward/backward etc) and you are trying to query dom on that changed page

Comment: What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: It is hard to say from this meager information you provided- post what you want-what you tried and what the error completely.

Comment: I added more details here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34112775/python-web-elements-selenium-stale

Comment: @Slslam, just wondering if you have had a chance to check out the link?